getStatic prop replacement in next 13+
I have a small blog in next js with a few blogposts. The blogposts are accessed through the file system.
What I want to do: Statically pre-render the blogposts. Before I would use getStaticProps and getStaticPaths like this:

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const { slug } = params;

  const postData = getPostData(slug);

  return {
    props: {
      post: postData,
    },
    revalidate: 600,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const postFilenames = getPostsFiles();

  const slugs = postFilenames.map((fileName) => fileName.replace(/\.md$/, ''));

  return {
    paths: slugs.map((slug) => ({ params: { slug } })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

What is the equivalent with app based routing?
i find example here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#generate-only-a-subset-of-params
but I struggle to translate it to this new code. Also - my posts are imported from file system so it feels wrong to use fetch.
